# Sending JavaScript URL Commands to UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, uibutton, iboutlet

So I was looking to create a UIBarButton, via IBOutlet, and send a JavaScript code to the WebView through this button. This is what I have so far but it keeps returning an error:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)emailCodePhone:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"javascript:location.href="mailto:someone@something.com?body="+document.getElementById("code").value;"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webViewPhone loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

**ViewController.m Error**
[image: Error Screenshot]

---

```
javascript:location.href="mailto:someone@something.com?body="+document.getElementById("code").value;
```

^ This being the JavaScript code I want sent to the UIWebView so whatever's located in the Textarea (who's ID is *code*), will be emailed to *someone@something.com*.

Please also specify if theres an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown because your string is ending prematurely at the first quotation mark inside it. You need to "escape" the quotations within your string with a backslash:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"javascript:location.href=\"mailto:...`